# Разделить массивные запросы к базе данных Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

существует ли способ разделить все тяжелые запросы к базе на части при достижении лимита памяти или времени?

Comment: можно... смотря только что за запросы

Comment: НУ что бы все запросы к бд при достижении лимита автоматом разделялись на части, то есть движок автоматом следит за запросами и разделяет их если они потребляют много памяти, пусть даже время на запрос тратится больше.

Comment: так движок БД это уже давно за Вас делает